# Pandas HDF5 append time series fails

Tags: pandas, append, time-series, hdf5

Going through the documentation of pandas HDF5 usability (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-hdf5) the given example raises an error:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

store = pd.HDFStore('store.h5')

np.random.seed(1234)

index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=8)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 3), index=index)

store['df'] = df

df1 = df[0:4]
df2 = df[4:]
store.append('df', df1)
store.append('df', df2)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-225-ef7f2e059c6a>", line 1, in <module>
    store.append('df', df1)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 919, in append
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 1252, in _write_to_group
    raise ValueError('Can only append to Tables')
ValueError: Can only append to Tables
```

Has something changed here? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable `append` by default store in the table format by setting the following option at the beginning as your store behaves like a `DF` currently:

```
pd.set_option('io.hdf.default_format','table')
```

[`Docs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#table-format)

Comment: Hmm, I try it and for me it return same error. for you it works?

Comment: It sometimes works, sometimes not. If I changed name`pd.HDFStore('store1.h5')` , it doesnt work.

Comment: Are you sure you are setting it after the import statements? It doesn't work once you set it after `store['df'] = df`.

Comment: I set it first, interesting.

Comment: Ok, I do not use `HDF5` very often, if your aswer will be accepted, I will +1

Comment: Nice to know that this default can be altered! Thank you!

Comment: @NickilMaveli Spent over 2 hours on this. Was almost giving up on HDF5 for Parquet, before I found this. Thank you. This is the right answer